# Passing two variables onclick back to same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to able to click on list element and depending on which I am clicking, 2 variables will be displayed on the same page.

I have 2 variables which are defined in the html code ( this could be changed as I am hardcoding them variables into the html ):

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="('6','67')">Text 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="('22','240')">Text 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="('34','56')">Text 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Later I would like to pick up both variables with PHP $_POST like this:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['var1'];
    echo $_POST['var2'];
?>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: have you already tried something ?

Comment: why do you want to use `_POST` later on ?

Comment: Use array. HTML/JavaScript can post arrays. And later, you can acces them like `$_POST['data'][0]`

Comment: I would be grateful for peace of code, as I've tried few things and they didn't work.

Comment: @karthikr I don't need to, just don't want to use GET if that is what you asking for

Comment: sure.. check out my answer. It does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myFunction('6','67')">Text 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myFunction('22','240')">Text 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myFunction('34','56')">Text 3</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
   function myFunction(a, b){
      $.ajax(function(){
          url: <yourURL>,
          data: {'a': a, 'b': b }
          success: function(){
               //access the variables here. 
          }

      });
   }

</script>
```

Comment: sorry for lame question, but how to pass them to the same page where my clicked list item is?

Comment: your ajax request responds to the same page. It does not do a page reload, but stays on the same page and fetches the results for you

Answer (score 0):

use $.post()

**html**

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#" onclick="callFunction('6','67')">Text 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" onclick="callFunction('22','240')">Text 2</a></li>
 ...
```

**jquery**

```
function callFunction(var1,var2){
   $.post('path/to/your/php/page',{'data1':var1,'data2':var2},function(result){
         alert('success');     
   })
}
```

and you can get the posted data in php by `$_POST`

**php**

```
$data1 = $_POST['data1'];
$data2 = $_POST['data2'];
echo $data1 " , " $data2;
```